# Clarify "Syntax highlighting for code": specify where to put "language-all:" directive

Tags: bug, syntax-highlighting, help-center, editing-help

On the page [Markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), section [Syntax highlighting for code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) needs to be clarified. Original text:

> To specify a syntax highlighting language to be used not only for the next, but for all following code blocks, use:
>
> ```
> <!-- language-all: lang-html -->
> ```
>
> To specify that you don't want any syntax highlighting for a code block, use:
>
> ```
> <!-- language: lang-none -->
> ```

Specify that you should add these directives to the **body** of the post, **not** to the inside of the code block. Example:

```
 <!-- language-all: lang-html -->  
 some text  
 CODE BLOCK 
 more text  
 ANOTHER CODE BLOCK
```